Interpretation of $z^{-1} = \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$
Given some complex number $z = x+iy = r e^{i \theta}$. Unless $z=0$, there exists some $z^{-1}$ such that $zz^{-1}= 1$. It is easy to find algebraically and is one of the first things learnt regarding complex numbers. I am aware of the argument $\theta$ of a complex number not adhering to Cauchy-Riemann conditions and hence not being complex differentiable, however, we can see that
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},$$
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$
and hence we get that
$$z^{-1} = \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}.$$
I struggle to interpret this meaningfully. That the inverse of a complex number is the component sum of the rate of changes of $\theta$. Any help is appreciated! As a sidenote, this seems so easily derivable that I am surprise that I have not seen this anywhere before.
Edit: My guess is that it has to do with Riemann spheres, but I am not knowledgeable enough to say for sure, and much less to prove it.

By the triple product rule, the RHS has imaginary-to-real-part ratio $-\partial y/\partial x=-\tan\theta$ as expected of $z^{-1}$. The hard part is interpreting the $\partial\theta/\partial y$ coefficient in $\Re z^{-1}$ being $1$, but it certainly should be dimensionless if we say $z$ has the units of length.

What exactly does the last sentence mean? Interpreting the partial derivative coefficient as $1$ being the hard part?

I mean interpreting why $k=1$ is true in $z^{-1}=k\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}+ik\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}$.

I am by no means an expert in complex analysis. What do you suggest as an interpretation?

"holding $i$ constant"?

@user619894 I know it sounds silly but I just meant keeping it there instead of considering it in any equation, and complex differentiating or something. I will remove it though

For what it's worth, here is a complex derivation:
$$\theta~=~{\rm Im}\ln z~=~\frac{\ln z-\ln\bar{z}}{2i}$$
so OP's title formula follows by differentiation:
$$2i\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial z}~=~\frac{1}{z}, $$
or equivalently,
$$ \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial \ln z}~=~\frac{1}{2i}, $$
which reflects that $\theta$ is an affine function of $\ln z$ with complex slope $\frac{1}{2i}$.

I'm looking for an interpretation, as I've already derived it. Any ideas?

I'd consider what happens geometrically to $\theta$ when $z$ changes. When $z$ changes parallel to the $z$ direction, $\theta$ is unchanged, but when $z$ is changed in a direction orthogonal to $z$, $\theta$ varies: $\theta(z+\delta z)\sim \theta(z) +|{\delta z_{\perp} \over z}|$

I think differential forms actually paint a decent picture.
To give an overview, we consider the action of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ and observe that the differential form $d{\theta}$ is invariant under the action of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ (rotation and scaling).
This means that for every tangent vector on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ with $(x, y)$ as the base point, we can pushforward the tangent vector to the tangent space at $(1, 0)$ via the action of $z^{-1} = (x + i y)^{-1}$ and evaluate the differential form at the pushforward vector.
With an appropriate choice of the tangent vector, we can recover the equation in question.
We define the action of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ as
\begin{equation}
    z = a + i b \mapsto A(z) := \begin{pmatrix}
        a & -b \\
        b & a
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Note that this map has an inverse given by
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & -b \\
        b & a
    \end{pmatrix}
    \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & -b \\
        b & a
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        i \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    a + i b.
\end{equation}
Since the action can be decomposed into rotation and scaling, while $d{\theta}$ is invariant under rotation and scaling, meaning that for every tangent vector $v$ at arbitrary $(x, y)$ and $w \in\mathbb{C}^\times$, we have
\begin{equation}
    d{\theta}|_{(x, y)} (v) = d{\theta}|_{A(w) (x,y)} (A(w)_* v)
\end{equation}
where star denotes pushforward.
Also note that if $v = v_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, we have
\begin{equation}
    A(w)_* v = \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
    \end{pmatrix}
    A(w)
    \begin{pmatrix}
        v_x \\
        v_y
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Observe that the RHS of the equation in question can be written as
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} + i \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} = d{\theta}|_{(x, y)} \left( i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \right).
\end{equation}
So we set $w = z^{-1} = (x + i y)^{-1}$, then invariance of $d{\theta}$ tells us
\begin{equation}
    d{\theta}|_{(x, y)} \left( i \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \right)
    =
    d{\theta}|_{(1,0)} \left[ \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
    \end{pmatrix}
    A(z^{-1})
    \begin{pmatrix}
        i \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix} \right].
\end{equation}
Since $d{\theta}|_{(1,0)} = d{y}|_{(1,0)}$, the above equation is equal to
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    A(z^{-1})
    \begin{pmatrix}
        i \\
        1
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    z^{-1}.
\end{equation}

I don't exactly understand it yet (especially some of the later lines) but I will study them more and come back to this

+1 for the perspective of differential forms. I learned a bit of new theory studying your answer, so thank you!

Note that the given relation is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} 
    &= -\frac{\sin\theta}{r} \tag{1}\\
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y} 
    &= \frac{\cos\theta}{r}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
We derive (2) geometrically.
Equation (1) follows by a similar argument.
Note that $\partial\theta/\partial y$ tells us how the argument of a complex number changes with a change in its imaginary part.
Consider Figure 1 below, where we examine a change in $\theta$, $\delta\theta$, given a small change in $y$, $\delta y$.
By the law of sines,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin\delta\theta}{\delta y} 
    &= \frac{\sin\phi}{r}.\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin\delta\theta}{\delta y} 
    &= \frac{\cos(\theta+\delta\theta)}{r} 
    = \frac{\cos\theta \cos\delta\theta - \sin\theta \sin\delta\theta}{r}.
\end{align*}
From Equation (3) we see that for $r>0$, $|\delta y|\ll 1$ implies $|\delta \theta|\ll 1$.
Using the linear approximation, for small $\delta\theta$ we have
$\sin\delta\theta \approx \delta\theta$
and
$\cos\delta\theta \approx 1$.
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\delta\theta}{\delta y} &\approx\frac{\cos\theta}{r}.
\end{align*}
(This approximation is good to corrections of order $\delta\theta$.)
In the limit we find
$\partial\theta/\partial y = \cos(\theta)/r$.

Figure 1
Addendum$\def\vz{{\bf z}} 
\def\vg{{\bf g}}$
We continue to think in terms of two-dimensional calculus.
Note that $z=x+i y$ may be represented as the two-dimensional vector
$\vz = \langle x,y\rangle = r\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$.
We have
\begin{align*}
\nabla_\vz \theta 
    &= \langle\theta_x,\theta_y\rangle 
    = \frac{1}{r}\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle.
\end{align*}
Thus, the gradient of $\theta$ has no component in the radial direction since
$\vz\cdot \nabla_\vz\theta = 0$.
We find that $\theta$ changes maximally for changes in $\vz$ that are perpendicular to $\vz$, i.e., along curves of constant modulus (circles centered at the origin).
This makes good geometric sense.
The multidimensional calculus language can be translated to that of complex analysis.
In my opinion, for this problem we only add cognitive load.
I give a sketch here.
The equation
$2i \partial_z\theta = 1/z$ is equivalent to
$2\partial_{\bar z}\theta = i/\bar z$.
Note that $2\partial_{\bar z}\theta$ is the complex representation of the gradient of $\theta$ since
$2\partial_{\bar z}\theta = \theta_x+i\theta_y$.
Define two complex numbers to be orthogonal if
$\Re \bar z z' = \Re z\bar z' = x x' + y y' = 0$.
This agrees with our notion of orthogonality for vectors.
We immediately find
$\Re ((2\partial_{\bar z}\theta)\bar z) = 0$, agreeing with the conclusions above.
We define the bijection $\Phi:\mathbb C\to \mathbb R^2$ by
$\Phi(z) = \langle \Re z,\Im z\rangle$.
Note that $\Phi^{-1}$ is given by
$\Phi^{-1}(\vz) = x+i y$, where $\vz = \langle x,y\rangle$.
We post a selection of results below.
\begin{align*}
z &= x+i y\\
z' &= x'+i y' \\
\vz &= \Phi(z) = \langle x,y\rangle \\
\vz' &= \Phi(z') = \langle x',y'\rangle \\
\bar z z' &= (x x'+y y')+i(x y'-x'y) \\
&= \vz\cdot \vz' + i \vz\times\vz' 
    & \textrm{dot, cross} \\
\\
2\partial_{\bar z} &= \partial_x + i\partial_y \\ 
\nabla &= \nabla_\vz = \langle\partial_x,\partial_y\rangle \\
2\partial_{\bar z} f &= f_x + i f_y 
    & \textrm{$f$ real-valued} \\ 
\Phi(2\partial_{\bar z} f) &= \nabla f 
    & \textrm{gradient} \\ 
g &= u+i v 
    & \textrm{$g$ complex-valued}\\ 
\vg &= \Phi(g) = \langle u,v\rangle \\ 
2\partial_z g &= \nabla\cdot\vg + i\nabla\times\vg 
    & \textrm{divergence, curl} \\ 
2\partial_z(2\partial_{\bar z}) &= \partial_x^2+\partial_y^2 = \nabla^2 
    & \textrm{Laplacian} \\ 
&\vdots 
\end{align*}

I guess you haven't found anything about this relation, because it isn't related to a specific property of complex numbers, but it comes from a general behaviour of exponential functions, which is somewhat too trivial to be named.
Indeed, let's consider an exponential function in a one-dimensional real space, i.e. $f(t) = Ae^{\lambda t}$. Then, its derivative is given by $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t} = \lambda f$, hence $\lambda\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}f} = \frac{1}{f}$, because $t$ depends logarithmically on $f$.
Now, the complex number $z = z(r,\theta) = re^{i\theta}$ corresponds to a bivariate analog, so that $\theta = \theta(z,\bar{z}) = -i\ln\frac{z}{r} = \frac{\ln z - \ln \bar{z}}{2i}$ also depends logarithmically on $z$, hence $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y} + i \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} = 2i\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}z} = \frac{1}{z}$, where $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}$ is a Wirtinger derivative. Note that, in comparison with the one-dimensional real case, the 2-factors are due to both contributions of the variable $z$ and its complex conjugate $\bar{z}$ to $\theta$.

+1 as this partially answers my question, and I have noticed this property yes. However, with focus on the complex numbers, I am looking for an interpretation- for example, a geometric picture of this relation. If you have any then edit it into the question :)

@Mako  Geometrically speaking, the quantity $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}z}$ is part of the (inverse) polar Jacobian associated to the change of coordinates $(z,\bar{z}) \mapsto (r,\theta)$, which is an overcomplicated way to translate that $e^{i\theta}$ is a rotation ultimately.
